# Extending Magento's functions in a new module

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to wrap my head around how to use Magento's native functions in a new module.  So for a simple example lets say I have a basic shell like :

app/code/local/Me/Test/Block/Container.php

```
<?php
class Me_Test_Block_Container extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
}
```

and in the layout.xml I am inserting design blocks unique to category and product page :

```
<catalog_category_layered>
     <reference name="after_body_start">
            <block type="test/container" name="test.container" template="test/category_container.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_layered>  
   <catalog_product_view>
     <reference name="after_body_start">
            <block type="test/container" name="test.container" template="test/product_container.phtml"/>
        </reference>
     </catalog_product_view>
</catalog_category_layered>
```

In those phtml I am trying to use functions to get current category on category page, and get product sku on product page.  So for the category page in my category_container.phtml I am trying to use the function

`<?php $_category  = $this->getCurrentCategory();?>`

But it returns blank.  Can someone please help me understand more about this?  I copied the `getCurrentCategory` function into Container.php but that did not work.  Should I be changing the block type in the layout.xml to be able to use that function or what is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get the category this way:

```
$_category = Mage::registry('current_category');
```

and the product like this:

```
$_product = Mage::registry('current_product');
```

Before using it check it their value is not `null`.